# generator expression combined line comprehension execution steps

Tags: python

```
[print(x) for x in ((x ** 2) for x in range(5))]
```

### output

```
0

1

4

9

16

[None, None, None, None, None]
```

I have found some explanations about a generator. Their examples are simple and easy to understand. However, I am still confused with the execution steps and the output.

Comment: `print(x)` *returns* `None`. That's why the comprehension produces the output (last line) it does. `print(x)` also has the *side effect* of printing the value `x`. The question becomes: what is the actual purpose of your code?
You should generally avoid using comprehension for side effects of the involved expressions! They exist to build data structures, not log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[print(x) for x in ((x ** 2) for x in range(5))]` if you're using the print method, its return value is **None** and therefore you have all **None** elements in your final list. If the desired output was to have all elements in the list, you should consider not using `print`.

```
l=[x for x in ((x ** 2) for x in range(5))]
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```